# kendo combobox send value to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, combobox, kendo-ui

I am trying to implement kendo ui combobox instead of normal dropdownlistfor. So, in my razor view, I replaced the code

```
@Html.DropDownList("clientid", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)clientList, "-- Select --",     new { id="ddClients", name="ddClients"})
```

with

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
    .Name("ddClients")
    .Filter("contains")
    .Placeholder("-- Select --")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .BindTo((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)clientList)
)
```

however in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClientDashboard(tblclient objClient, String submitButton)
{
...
}
```

I am not getting the client into tblclient object!

Please help.

Comment: you mean you want to send the data or the combobox id??

Comment: the combo box is looking to bind to an object called `ddlClients` not `objClient`

Comment: @Rudresh - Basically I would like to send the client id corresponding to the client selected in the dropdown.

Comment: @CSharper ddClients is just the name of the combobox. I would like to retrieve the selected value in the controller...

Comment: @rmdev exactly, so it is looking to bind to that name, in your controller you must put `int ddlClients`

Comment: @rmdev glad it worked :) I posted as answer

Comment: Thanks for the help @CSharper can you please look at the other problem of mine - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522401/kendo-combobox-reset-after-loading-back-view-from-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller to this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClientDashboard(int ddClients, String submitBUtton)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind the selected value directly to the view model.

For example:

Add the id to your model:

```
public Int32? ClientID {get; set;}
```

Add a hidden field to your view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ClientID)
```

Add a click event to assign the ClientID to the hidden field:

```
    $("#submitButton").on("click", function () {
        var combo = $("#ddClients").data("kendoComboBox");
        $("#ClientID").val(combo.value());
    });
```

Update: I just noticed that all you have to do is change the name of the combobox to ClientID and the value is bound to the view model without the hidden field and javascript.